# How do I get a reference to an IHostedService via Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.1

## Details

I have attempted to create a background processing structure using the recommended `IHostedService` interface in ASP.NET 2.1. I register the services as follows:

```
services.AddSingleton<AbstractProcessQueue<AbstractImportProcess>>();
services.AddHostedService<AbstractBackgroundProcessService<AbstractImportProcess>>();

services.AddSignalR();
```

The `AbstractProcessQueue` is just a wrapper around a `BlockingCollection` of processes that can be enqueued and dequeued. The `AbstractBackgroundProcessService` implements the `IHostedService` interface and looks at the queue for new processes it can start.

Now, the trouble starts when, inside a `SignalR` hub, I attempt to get a reference to the background processing service via the `Dependency Injection` mechanisms. I have tried the following solutions, but none seem to be working as intended:

#### Option 1:

```
public HubImportClient(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    //This returns null.
    var service = provider.GetService<AbstractBackgroundProcessService<AbstractImportProcess>>();
}
```

#### Option 2:

```
public HubImportClient(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    //This returns null.
    var service = (AbstractBackgroundProcessService<AbstractImportProcess>) provider.GetService(typeof(AbstractBackgroundProcessService<AbstractImportProcess>>));
}
```

#### Option 3:

```
public HubImportClient(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    //This throws an exception, because the service is missing.
    var service = provider.GetRequiredService<AbstractBackgroundProcessService<AbstractImportProcess>>();
}
```

#### Option 4:

```
public HubImportClient(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    //This throws an exception, because the service is missing.
    var service = (AbstractBackgroundProcessService<AbstractImportProcess>) provider.GetRequiredService(typeof(AbstractBackgroundProcessService<AbstractImportProcess>);
}
```

#### Option 5:

```
public HubImportClient(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    //This returns a correct service, but prevents me from adding additional AbstractBackgroundProcessService implementations with different type parameters.
    //Additionally, it seems like this reference was newly created, and not the instance that was created on application startup (i.e. the hash codes are different, and the constructor is called an additional time).
    var service = provider.GetService<IHostedService>();
    if(service is AbstractBackgroundProcessService<AbstractProcessService>)
    {    this.Service = (AbstractBackgroundProcessService<AbstractProcessService>) service;}
}
```

#### Option 6:

```
public HubImportClient(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    //This works similarly to the previous option, and allows multiple implementations, but the constructor is still called twice and the instances thus differ.
    AbstractBackgroundProcessService<AbstractImportProcess> service = null;
    foreach(IHostedService service in provider.GetServices<IHostedService>())
    {
        if(service is AbstractBackgroundProcessService<AbstractImportProcess>)
        {
            service = (AbstractBackgroundProcessService<AbstractImportProcess>) service;
            break;
        }
    }  
}
```

#### Option 7:

```
public HubImportClient(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    //This just skips the for each loop all together, because no such services could be found.
    AbstractBackgroundProcessService<AbstractImportProcess> service = null;
    foreach(AbstractBackgroundProcessService<AbstractImportProcess> current in provider.GetServices<AbstractBackgroundProcessService<AbstractImportProcess> >())
    {
        service = current;
        break;
    }    
}
```

#### Option 8:

```
//This works, but prevents multiple implementations again.
public HubImportClient(IHostedService service)
{
    this.Service = service;   
}
```

#### Option 9:

```
//This does not work again.
public HubImportClient(AbstractBackgroundProcessService<AbstractImportProcess> service)
{
    this.Service = service;   
}
```

## Question

So then my question remains: how am I supposed to get a reference to an `IHostedService` implementation so that:

(a): I can inject multiple instances of the service that differ only by their type parameter (e.g. a hosted service for `AbstractImportProcess`es as well as one for `AbstractExportProcess`es)

(b): there is only ever one instance of the `IHostedService` for that specific type parameter.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why do you need the servince instance directly? This is atypical. All you should need to do is merely register the `IHostedService` implementation. ASP.NET Core takes care of instantiating and running it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt i expect to acquire the state of the configured active instance of my HostedService, that it would be the entire purpose of having Start/Stop, that my scoped services receive the hot instance bootstrapped by my HostedService.

Comment: Ultimately i just added a static property to my HostedService to register against in DI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There has been some discussion around this topic. For example, see: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1489. One of the problems that you'll run into is that hosted services are added as transient services (from ASP.NET Core 2.1+), meaning that resolving a hosted service from the dependency injection container will result in a new instance each time.

The general advice is to encapsulate any business logic that you want to share with or interact from other services into a specific service. Looking at your code, I suggest you implement the business logic in the `AbstractProcessQueue<AbstractImportProcess>` class and make executing the business logic the only concern of `AbstractBackgroundProcessService<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your advice, combined with Chris Pratt's comment, have made me decide to move the business logic to the process queue and leave the hosted service for what it is. I don't quite understand why they have opted to add the hosted services as a transient dependency, but this solution will do for now. Thanks alot for the help!

Comment: That thread over there is really strange, i hope everyone here comments on it.

Answer (score 61):

Current workaround from mentioned [git page](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1489):

```
services.AddSingleton<YourServiceType>();
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(p => p.GetRequiredService<YourServiceType>());
```

Or, if your service implements some other interfaces:

```
services.AddSingleton<YourServiceType>();    
services.AddSingleton<IYourServiceType>(p => p.GetRequiredService<YourServiceType>());
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(p => p.GetRequiredService<YourServiceType>());
```

This creates your service as hosted (runs and stops at host's start and shutdown), as well as gets injected as depedency wherever you require it to be.

### Update:

I don't see this solution as a "workaround" anymore.

Instead, I would describe it this way: hosted component and a regular service are entities of different types, each one serving its own purpose.

The solution above, however, allows one to combine them, registering a hosted component as a service, which can be used in the dependency resolution chain.

Which is awesome.

Comment: Is there a better way available in dotnet 5?

Comment: Not sure how it works but when I run 
_serviceProvider.GetService<IHostedService>();  

I get my hosted service type back. Not sure how it will work with multiple hosted services.

Comment: @too No, and I don't think you could prove that some one-liner would be "better" for any reason except for being a one-liner.

Comment: Thank you @AgentFire ;) saved my day

Answer (score 30):

This is just a slight modification to the answer by @AgentFire.  This method is clearer and allows for several background hosted services in a single Web Service.

```
services.AddSingleton<YourServiceType>();
services.AddHostedService<YourServiceType>(p => p.GetRequiredService<YourServiceType>());
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest and cleanest solution. You could make it even simpler by omitting the first type parameter from the second line: `services.AddHostedService(p => p.GetRequiredService<YourServiceType>());`

Comment: Yup, that'll do it. Perfect!

Answer (score 6):

You get this directly from the `IServiceProvider` in dotnet core 3.1 and later:

```
var myHostedService = serviceProvider
    .GetServices<IHostedService>()
    .OfType<MyHostedService>()
    .Single();
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is complete solution based on @andyvan and @Hursev answers. As of 2022, seems to be more "current" and concise workaround, compare to accepted and most popular answers.

```
//regular implementation of Background/IHostedService. Nothing special.
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    
}

//Startup.cs or Program.cs
//Also standard. No extra code required.
services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();
services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();


//MyService is where we want to consume background servive
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly MyBackgroundService _service;

    public MyService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _service = serviceProvider.GetServices<IHostedService>().OfType<MyBackgroundService>().Single();
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        //Consume background service as any other DI services.
        _service.SomethingFromMyBackgroundService();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In .Net Core 3.1 and .Net 5.0you can get references to the existing instances of the Hosted Services with:
`IEnumerable<IHostedService> allHostedServices = this.serviceProvider.GetService<IEnumerable<IHostedService>>();`