# .NET Core Hosted Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I need to get a reference of registred hosted service:

```
services.AddHostedService<DataCollectingService>();
```

It implements interface `IHostedService` and it properly starts at web application start.

I need to get the ref of the service in some controller and access object public members.

The following code doesn't work. `xService` is null.

```
public IActionResult T()
{
    using (var serviceScope = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        var xService = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DataCollectingService>();

    }
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Comment: Why not ask for another service to ferry information between your controller and the hosted service? Some sort of caching layer.

Comment: That is my backup plan - use some static property which will be fillen by service after it starts. But i guess there is some "more correct" way to get the reference.

Comment: So according to the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/6e92fcad99b6a6e882ac8dc5ad817b558f603597/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.cs#L21) the item is registered as a `IHostedService`. You should be able to ask for an `IEnumerable<IHostedService>` in your controller's constructor. But I don't think you can ask for the hosted service directly by name.

Comment: Well you also create new scope in your code so your background service will immediately be out of scope then.

Comment: IEnumerable<IHostedService> in controller's constructor is not working. It creates a new instance but i need the origin reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a reference to an IHostedService via Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036998/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-an-ihostedservice-via-dependency-injection-in-asp-ne)

Comment: Has anyone deployed .NET Core Hosted Service in IIS Server?

Answer (score 1):

The answer that works in .Net Core 3.1+ was given by [gunr2171](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043380/gunr2171) in the [3rd comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532855/net-core-hosted-service/67539054#comment99649056_56532855) of the original question:

```
IEnumerable<IHostedService> allHostedServices = this.serviceProvider.GetService<IEnumerable<IHostedService>>();
```

Will return references to the existing instances of the Hosted Services.

Answer (score 0):

I have temporaly handled that by storing reference staticly in class which is set durring start.

Answer (score 0):

I would move all the functionality to a Singleton, then in my startup I would do something like

```
services.AddSingleton<DataCollectingService>();
services.AddHostedService<HostedServiceUsingTheDataCollectionService>();
```

Then I could inject the Singleton in the controllers.

I am not sure if Core will handle the same reference (I think in core 3 will be the case, not so sure for <=2.2), but I would give a try.